# Generate request with raw post json, headers and additional parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, rspec

What I need:

- send a POST request in an rspec test
- with raw json data
- a specific header
- beside that I need two more params in my action that are usually generated from the URI by routing.

Any suggestions?

I know that I can use

```
post :action, 'raw data', 'CONTENT_TYPE' => 'application/json', 'custom-header' => 'value'
```

But how do I add that two params?

#### UPDATE:

I can send the request I need with curl this way:

```
curl -v -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H 'custom-header: value' -X POST -d @data.txt http://url.of.my.app
```

Here `@data.txt` is a file with a raw data. And the parameters I've mentioned in the last bullet are taken from url

Answer (score 0):

you can pass custom things in a third parameter.

```
post :action, { your: json }, { content_type: 'application/json', custom_header: 'my_header }
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Integration/RequestHelpers.html#method-i-get

Comment: Yes, I can, that's what I've written. The question is how do I deal with two parameters?

Comment: For me, the raw json has to already be a Hash and you just add the two params there like rails do.

Comment: Yes, it may be. But as additional header I'm sending a signature generated from raw data string. And I'm verifying it later. I can't add anything more to original data

Comment: Except doing a real query against a rails instance with cukes or something... I don't know. Sorry